# PHP PDO for getting MySQL fileds name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function from class that gets data from MySQL. All works OK but I also want to know how I can get the column names for MySQL data.

Here is my code :

```
public static function getTickets(){
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "select tickets.*,customers.* from tickets,customers where 
            (tickets.ticket_customer_id = customers.customer_id)  order by tickets.ticket_open_date desc ";

    $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while($row=$st->fetch()) { 
        $tickets = New Tickets($row);
        $list[] = $tickets;
    }

    //total rows of customer
    $sql = "select FOUND_ROWS() as totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query($sql)->fetch();
    $conn=null;

    $columnCount = $st->columnCount();

    //pass the values to page
    return (array("results"=>$list ,"totalRows"=>$totalRows,"columnCount"=>$columnCount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you need here, but looking at your code I would say that everything you need you can get from the very data you are fetching

```
public static function getTickets($conn){
     $sql = "select tickets.*,customers.* from tickets,customers where 
     (tickets.ticket_customer_id = customers.customer_id)  order by tickets.ticket_open_date desc ";
     $st = $conn->query($sql);

     $list = array();
     while($row=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $list[] = New Tickets($row);
         $columnNames = array_keys($row);
     }

     //total rows of customer
     $totalRows = count($list);
     $columnCount = count($columnNames);

     //pass the values to page
    return (array("results"=>$list ,"totalRows"=>$totalRows,"columnCount"=>$columnCount));
}
```